# What's wrong in the method?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Given an array of size n, find the majority element. The majority element is the element that appears more than ⌊ n/2 ⌋ times.

You may assume that the array is non-empty and the majority element always exist in the array.

I have tried the following code, some of the test cases aren't working.

```
class Solution {
      public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
            int x = (nums.length)/2;
            int temp=0;
            for (int i=0;i<nums.length-1; i++){
                 if (nums[i]>nums[i+1]){
                    temp=nums[i+1];
                    nums[i+1]=nums[i];
                    nums[i]=temp;
                 }

            }
            if (nums.length==1){
                return nums[0];
            }
            if (nums.length%2==0){
                return nums[x];
            }
            else {
                return nums[(nums.length/2)+1];
            }
       }
}
```

When input is [3,3,4], my code outputs 4 instead of 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: I don't see how your algorithm would find the majority element at all. The `for` loop puts the biggest number in the last element (and exchanges some others). Perhaps you intended this to be a sort, but you only  did one loop, so it's not a sort.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Array`'s are zero based you need to do:

```
return nums[(nums.length/2)];
```

Instead of:

```
return nums[(nums.length/2)+1];
```

So that if the `Array` is of 3 elements, it will return the middle element instead of the last.

Also your algorithm isn't correct. For the `Array` [1,1,2,0] it will return `0`. The problem is that since your sort is only one loop, it does not guarantee that it will sort the entire `Array`. Instead you can use `Arrays.sort`:

```
public static int foo(int[] nums) {
    int x = (nums.length)/2;
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    if (nums.length==1){
        return nums[0];
    }
    if (nums.length%2==0){
        return nums[x];
    }
    else {
        return nums[(nums.length/2)];
    }

}
```

Since there is a stipulation that *The majority element is the element that appears more than ⌊ n/2 ⌋ times.* this can be simplified to:

```
 public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
     Arrays.sort(nums);
     return nums[nums.length/2]
}
```

Comment: Is the logic he has given is correct to solve the given problem statement?

Comment: @GarvitKhamesra I'm assuming the OP means majority element as the element that occurs the most.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the frequency of each value in the array and if its greater that n/2, return it like below. I think the logic in here would be much clearer

```
  public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(list);

        for (int value: set) {
            if (Collections.frequency(list, value) > list.size() / 2) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Repeating `Collections.frequency` for each element actually makes this an O(n^2) algorithm. So sorting would be more efficient at least on average. It's better to collect a map of frequencies.

Comment: If majority element is always in the array, sorting it and get the middle element would be the best. Agreed

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class spl {
    public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
       int x = (nums.length)/2;
       int counter=1;
       int majEl = -1; /// for no majority element is -1;
       boolean flag=false;
       bubbleSort(nums);

        for(int i=0;i<(nums.length+1)/2;i++) {
             if(flag) {break;}
            if(nums[i]==nums[i+1])
                while(nums[i]==nums[i+1]) {
                    ++counter;
                    i++;}
                    if(counter>=x) {
                        majEl=nums[i];
                        flag=true;
                        break;

                    }
                    else {counter=1;}
                }

        if (nums.length==1){
            return nums[0];
        }
        else {return majEl;}
   }

    private void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {

            int n = arr.length;  
            int temp = 0;  
             for(int i=0; i < n; i++){  
                     for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){  
                              if(arr[j-1] > arr[j]){  

                                     temp = arr[j-1];  
                                     arr[j-1] = arr[j];  
                                     arr[j] = temp;  
                             }  

                     }  
             }  

    }
}
```

Explain: nums[8,7,3,3,3], After BubbleSort[3,3,3,7,8] In the loop you check if nums[0]==nums[1], ++counter, nums[1]==nums[2], ++counter;, so counter is 3, bigger that array.size, so you found the majority element

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: Once the array is sorted, you don't really need to look for the frequency - the OP's idea was right. If there is a majority element (and the instructions assure that there is one), then in a sorted array, it will be the element in the middle of the array. Also, bubble sort is O(n^2) and should be avoided in favor of built-in, fast sorts.